# How can I override property in this situation

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm new to JavaScript so if I'm misunderstanding a concept, please feel free to let me know.

I have the following class:

```
var Human = function () {};
Object.defineProperty(Human.prototype, 'name', {
     get: function () { return this._name; },
     set: function (value) { this._name = value; },
     configurable: true,
     enumerable: true
});
```

I then define the following child object:

```
var Man = function () {};
Man.prototype = new Human(); //Am I inherting Human's prototype (and properties) here?
Man.prototype.name = 'Matt'; //If so, I should be setting Man's name property (overriding the value inherited from Human)
```

However, `console.log(Man.name)` prints out `""`.

Why is this and how can I correctly override `Human`'s property?

**PS**:

I have also tried

```
Man.name = 'Matt';
```

instead of

```
Man.prototype.Name = 'Matt';
```

But I got the same behaviour.

**Ps2:**

I should also note that if I execute `console.log(Man.prototype._name)` i get the expected output `"Matt"`

Comment: `Man.name` is the _function name_, which has nothing to do with that `name` property. If you did `var Man = function someName(){};`, `Man.name` would be `"someName"`. Anyway, what exactly is your expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are setting prototype property, you need to instantiate a new object from this constructor, then prototype will be used to construct new object instance:

```
var Man = function () {};
Man.prototype = new Human();
Man.prototype.name = 'Matt';

var man = new Man(); // <--- this is new man
console.log(man.name);
```

However, you probably don't want all `Man` instancies to have the same name - what happens when you put stuff in `prototype`, it's get shared by all instancies. This makes more sense:

```
var Man = function () {};
Man.prototype = new Human();

var man = new Man();
man.name = 'Matt';
console.log(man.name);
```

Here you only set *own* property of the the object `man`.

Comment: This is the exact behaviour that I wanted to achieve. Defining a property in a super class and overwriting it in the child. Thank you!